# Search an HTML Table ignoring capital letters

Tags: javascript, search, html-table, livesearch

I generate an html table from a .csv using php.

I got this JavaScript Livesearch that works pretty decent, I use it to search the table.

This is the code:

```
function doSearch() {
    var searchText = document.getElementById('searchTerm').value;
    var targetTable = document.getElementById('dataTable');
    var targetTableColCount;


    //Loop through table rows
    for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < targetTable.rows.length; rowIndex++) {
        var rowData = '';

        //Get column count from header row
        if (rowIndex == 0) {
            targetTableColCount = targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.length;
            continue; //do not execute further code for header row.
        }

        //Process data rows. (rowIndex >= 1)
        for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < targetTableColCount; colIndex++) {
            rowData += targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.item(colIndex).textContent;
        }

        //If search term is not found in row data
        //then hide the row, else show
        if (rowData.indexOf(searchText) == -1)
            targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'none';
        else
            targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'table-row';
    }

    function capitaliseFirstLetter(string)
    {
        return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
    }
}
```

The search is case sensitive about capital letters, I would like it to ignore that, so that it will find the entries anyways.

If I search for "jon doe" I want to find: "jon doe", "Jon doe", "Jon Doe", "JON DOE", etc.

How can this be implemented into my existing code?

Comment: Have you tried comparing upper case to upper case, for example when you find the string you want to find, say Jon Doe, convert it to JON DOE and then with the string you're comparing it to, convert it to JON DOE also, that way you'll only ever compare all upper cases no matter what's in the table or what you're searching for.

Comment: That seems like a good idea to me, I am pretty new with JS though, could you maybe show me how you would do this in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do ToUpperCase to compare strings
for example:

```
var myName = 'Jon Doe';
```

Then you'd do the same for whatever name you're checking for

```
var searchName = GetElementById("MyTextbox");

var areEqual = myName.toUpperCase() === searchName.toUpperCase();
```

Then you can do

```
if(areEqual == True) {
    document.write("Names Match");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was not 100% of what I needed but it put me straight to the right direction :)

Comment: I don't know much about JavaScript so I didn't know how to add it into your existing code, glad I helped in some way though :)